# What's the proper term for run-time errors?

Tags: terminology

I know when you make a typo in your code, it's called a syntax error. but what do you call errors like using an element out of array bounds?

Comment: Err, runtime error? Of course that's an umbrella term and there are more specific names for each. Also, typos don't have to be syntax errors (print `fpp()` instead of `foo()`, perfectly valid syntax).

Comment: i meant errors that cause exceptions

Answer (score 0):

They're called runtime errors.

Comment: thank you. so it is caused by correctly written code which is badly applied

Comment: That's really a matter of definition - I personally wouldn't call any code that causes errors or exceptions "correctly written". Perhaps what you mean is that the code is *syntactically correct*, but contains bugs?!

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative term is, of course, *bugs*. I would say that *runtime errors* includes environmental problems such as network failure and disk corruption, whereas *bugs* are problems in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is [Logic error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error).

> Unlike a program with a syntax error, a program with a logic error is a valid program in the language, though it does not behave as intended.The only clue to the existence of logic errors is the production of wrong solutions.

Most introductory programming texts I've read divide programming errors into these two broad categories, syntax and logic errors.